Merge tris to quads with a specific condition
I have a mesh of tris that are differently sized (always sized in a power of 2).  I want to merge only the tris that align with eachother to a single quad.  It's hard to explain so I took a screenshot and manually painted red each edge I want to remove.
Notice that there are some tris that align and create a quad, but the quad is diagonal.  In this case I do not want to merge them (I've highlighted one example of this in green).  I also don't want to make any quads out of 4 tris, just if there are two tris that make a quad (i've highlighted an example of this in blue).  I don't want to merge them with any sort of "tolerance" - I only want them merged if the tris align exactly and will result in no change in the surface.
So far I've tried Tris to Quad feature and Limited Dissolve feature, but none had the right results.  Any way to do this quickly without having to go through each face would be awesome.
Thanks in advance!


It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.  (so they can test with)

good suggestion: https://blend-exchange.com/b/Pem0KDgp
